# Subtração direto na query de uma view?

Tags: sql

Tenho a `view` `dbo.ViewExportItensNotasFiscais`, tenho o campo `NFValIcmsSubs`, onde é necessário subtrair o valor do campo `NFValFCP` e manter o nome da coluna como `NFValIcmsSubs`

Como eu poderia fazer uma subtração direto da `Query` de uma `View`?

Answer (score 6):

Utilizando [Alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) no SQL.

```
SELECT (NFValIcmsSubs - NFValFCP) as NFValIcmsSubs FROM TABELA
```

Answer (score 3):

Especificamente para o seu caso a resposta do amigo Everson é a que atende a sua pergunta.

Porém o cliente MySQL pode efetuar também algumas operações com algum nível adicional de complexidade.

Exemplos:

```
SELECT (NFValIcmsSubs - NFValFCP)*2 as NFValIcmsSubs FROM TABELA

SELECT (NFValIcmsSubs - NFValFCP)*(FValIcmsSubs + NFValFCP) as NFValIcmsSubs FROM TABELA
```

Tal como nas operações de cálculo aritmético básicas, o MySQL também tem precedências entre operadores.
Assim, os operadores de multiplicação e de divisão são considerados antes dos operadores de adição e subtração.
Se dois operadores tiverem a mesma prioridade, a expressão é lida da esquerda para a direita.
Use os parênteses para forçar a priorização e para melhorar a legibilidade da expressão.